# Rust - Can't run complex terminal Command

Tags: rust

I'm trying to run a somewhat long command with rust:

```
rsync -avL --progress -e 'ssh -i ~/path/to/mypem.pem' ../directory/src/file.js user@computer:~/data/school
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
use std::process::Command;
let output = Command::new("rsync").args(&["-avL", "--progress", "-e", "'ssh", "-i", "~/path/to/mypem.pem'", "../directory/src/file.js", "user@computer:~/data/school"]).output().expect("BAD");

if !output.status.success() {
    let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr);
    print!("rustc failed and stderr was:\n{}", s);
}

println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout));
```

This doesn't seem to work at all. It gives me this error:

**Missing trailing-' in remote-shell command.**

**rsync error: syntax or usage error_**

I'd really appreciate any help with what I'm doing wrong here. I've checked the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) for Command

Comment: Try dropping the `'` in `'ssh ...'`. Its used for keeping the argument in one piece, suppressing whitespace-separation, on the shell and is not needed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the point of view of the rsync command, this bit:

```
ssh -i ~/path/to/mypem.pem
```

is one single argument, so you should not split it into multiple arguments.

Try this:

```
let output = Command::new("rsync").args(&["-avL", "--progress", "-e", "ssh -i ~/path/to/mypem.pem", "../directory/src/file.js", "user@computer:~/data/school"]).output().expect("BAD");
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a reason rust doesn't have a function to just type a singular string and run that? This seems much more complicated than it should be